# C# - Toast Notifications expire time extend

Tags: c#

It displays after 20 seconds but disappears after about 7 seconds, how to extend the expire time?

code :

```
  new ToastContentBuilder()
                        .AddArgument("action", "viewConversation")
                        .AddArgument("conversationId", 9813)
                        .AddText("User has administrator privileges.")
                        .AddText("Please restart your computer for changes to take effect!")
                            //.Show(); // Not seeing the Show() method? Make sure you have version 7.0, and if you're using .NET 6 (or later), then your TFM must be net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0 or greater
                            .Show(toast =>
                            {
                                toast.ExpirationTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(20);
                            });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications.
If we look in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.notifications.toastcontentbuilder.settoastduration?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.0) there is a method:

> ToastContentBuilder.SetToastDuration(ToastDuration)
>
> Sets the amount of time the Toast should display. You typically should
> use the Scenario attribute instead, which impacts how long a Toast
> stays on screen.

example:

```
new ToastContentBuilder()
                        .AddArgument("action", "viewConversation")
                        .AddArgument("conversationId", 9813)
                        .AddText("User has administrator privileges.")
                        .AddText("Please restart your computer for changes to take effect!")
                        .SetToastDuration(ToastDuration.Long) //ToastDuration is an enum that can be short or long
                            //.Show(); // Not seeing the Show() method? Make sure you have version 7.0, and if you're using .NET 6 (or later), then your TFM must be net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0 or greater
                            .Show(toast =>
                            {
                                toast.ExpirationTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(20);
                            });
```

Comment: so  how can we use this ? I use ".SetToastDuration(ToastDuration 20)" but no luck

Comment: I edited the answer providing an example, the ToastDuration is an enum, it can be Long or Short

Comment: The `ToastScenario` options do not answer the question. According to the documentation, the `toast.ExpirationTime` should be controlling how long the notification is displayed but it doesn't. It seems to be ignored.